# Importing labels at specific X,Y points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, excel

I am trying to load an excel file into ArcGIS Pro that has 3 columns x,y,label like this
X             Y        Code
396051.35 -616690.04 Ag01

606336.43 -616823.57 Ag02

I need to output a shapefile that has the labels (Ag01,Ag02...) posted at the XY location.

I tried add data-->x,y point data and pointed to the Excel file that has the data but this only imported the point not the label and it does not let me select the column header for X,Y and code values it just shows the numbers.

Could you help?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as a shapefile can't directly display text but only geographic feature, so having only point displayed is the expected behaviour. Is your problem how to display label in ArcPRO or how to import an Excel table in ArcPRO ?

Comment: @J.R I think the question is how to get the attributes as well as the point geometry from the Excel file into a (shapefile) feature class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the steps for one way to do this are:

1. Use Excel To Table to create a file geodatabase table with the same data as the Excel worksheet
2. Add an ID field to the table (Add Field) and calculate it to be equal to the OBJECTID (Calculate Field) - this means that it can be relied upon as a join field shortly
3. Use XY Table To Point to create a point feature class using the X,Y fields in the table
4. Use Join Field to join the table onto the point feature class using the ID field as the join field.